# Making changes in ELF file after dissassembly

Tags: disassembly, elf, hex

I am new to reverse engineering and after some research, I haven't found a clear way to do what I want to do.

I have an ELF file, but not the original source code that generated it. It is really simple and just prints some numbers. I wanted to make a small change in the range of numbers it prints. I have disassembled it and figured out where the change must be made, but I am not sure **how** to make this change.

Is there a way to edit disassembled code and still generate an executable file? Or should I figure out where in the hex file is the  corresponding information that I want to change and use a hex editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no details about the binary are provided in the question, only a general answer can be given. It sounds like you are trying to statically modify an executable ELF binary. This is also referred to as [patching](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17553/meaning-of-patching-binary-files). This is different from dynamic modification, or program runtime instrumentation.

#### Tools and Examples

Tools that can be used for patching include [`gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Patching.html), [`radare2`](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/basic_commands/write.html), [the ERESI suite](https://github.com/thorkill/eresi/wiki/TheELFsh), [`xxd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) and [`hexedit`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hexedit).

**Radare2**

[Patch a elf binary in linux with radare2](http://nighterse.blogspot.com/2016/07/i-have-binary-patching-and-done-lot-off.html)

[Tutorial 1 - Simple Patch](https://monosource.gitbooks.io/radare2-explorations/content/tut1/tut1_-_simple_patch.html)

[fixing bugs in binaries using r2](http://radare.org/get/ncn2010.pdf)

**GDB**

[Use gdb to Modify Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173850/use-gdb-to-modify-binary)

[Using GDB to modify an executable](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8200/using-gdb-to-modify-an-executable)

**xxd**

[Doing a Reverse Hex Dump](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/doing-reverse-hex-dump)

**hexedit**

[Modifying Linux ELF Binaries - Changing Callq Addresses](http://web.archive.org/web/20150105041523/https://www.pacificsimplicity.ca/blog/modifying-linux-elf-binaries-changing-callq-addresses)

#### Similar questions:

[How can I change the values in esp?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14936/how-can-i-change-the-values-in-esp?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How do I add functionality to an existing binary executable?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185/how-do-i-add-functionality-to-an-existing-binary-executable?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[What are the available libraries to statically modify ELF executables?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1843/what-are-the-available-libraries-to-statically-modify-elf-executables?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks! That was a great and complete answer. Turns out that what I needed was really simple. I used objdump to check the hex of the things that I needed to change and edited them using hexedit. But your answer will help me study more advanced techniques.